# Any ideas why my fixture won't load for Django test?

Tags: django, django-testing, django-tests

This is the first time I've tried loading a fixture for my unit tests in Django, and I have no idea why it won't load. I dumped the data from my app with `dumpdata` command and that works fine.  When I `loaddata` from command line or run my tests with `fixtures` set at my data file I get the following error:

```
DeserializationError: Problem installing fixture 'data.json': [u"'' value must be an integer."]
```

Tried with xml format:

```
ValidationError: [u"'' value must be an integer."]
```

It seems like Django is looking for an IntergerField, but it is blank? Anybody have any idea what is going on here or any way to get a more verbose error message that would maybe tell me what model it is on?

Comment: check the model related to the fixture it is trying to load, and see if it is a required field. If yes, it is a data issue. Just put in a valid integer value

Answer (score 0):

After dumping each individual model to determine which one caused the error, I found a field that was blank.  I don't understand why it didn't work being the field was set to `blank=True, null=True`.  Feel free to let me know.